# For loop inside function does'n seem to work properly in C

Tags: c

I have to create a function in c that one value and two pointers, verify if the value is a prime number or if it is a composite number, show the maximum and minimum divisors and return 1 for composite and 0 for prime. The problem is the minimum value is returned correctly but the maximum value returns something out of for loop restriction, for example:
n = 12
min is 2 max is 61
Why *max = i is returning a number bigger than the variable "value"?

Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int divs(int value, int *max, int *min)
{   
    for (int i = 2; i < value; i++)
    {  
        if (value % i == 0){
            if (*max == 0){
                *min = i;
            }
            *max = i;   
        }   
    }
    if (*max != 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;

}

int main(void)
{
   int n,max = 0,min = 0,result;

   printf("type a number bigger than 2\n");
   scanf("%d",&n);

   divs(n,&max, &min);
   result = divs(n,&max, &min);
   if (result == 1)
      printf("min is: %d max is: %d",min,max);


   printf("%d\n",result);


   return 0;

}
```

Comment: What input gives you wrong results?

Comment: Notice that you are missing a `\n` in the first `printf`. So for input 12 the print out will show 61 but that's 6 from `max` and 1 from `result`. By adding a newline to the first print, the print out will be more clear.

Comment: regarding: `divs(n,&max, &min);
   result = divs(n,&max, &min);`  why call `divs()` twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine, you just left out a \n in your printf statement in main, change to this:

```
printf("min is: %d max is: %d\n",min,max);
```

Which caused your next printf ('1') to print right next to it.

Answer (score 0):

You did not print a new line:

```
if (result == 1)
  printf("min is: %d max is: %d",min,max);

printf("%d\n",result);
```

When `result` is 1, you first print `min is: 2 max is: 6`, and then you print `1`.

Change the first part to:

```
if (result == 1)
    printf("min is: %d max is: %d\n", min, max);
```